# Are there differences between the SOE L4 mission agents?

Tags: eve-online

Are the new sister's of eve level 4 mission agents that were recently released similar to the Osmon L4 agent in the missions they give, or are the rats' factions different?

I fly a nightmare usually so if there's some missions that are more laser friendly then I'm definitely interested in moving there from Osmon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agents of the same corp and level are handing out the same pool of missions. There is a factor of luck in getting good missions or missions you can run well. 
To get more efficinet people prefer corps that have agents close together, so you can pick from a bigger pool. And they have different ships and setups available for different kinds of missions.

Comment: Just to add one tiny detail: The pool of available missions is based on the region you're in, as far as I know even if you're working for the same corporation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lvl4 SOE agent at apaneke system, bloor raider region, mostly laser friendly missions. (I use Apocalypse Navy easily)